# What is the typical location of Table of Contents in a typical TeX article?

Tags: table-of-contents, article

I am doing a sample article to demonstrate my knowledge of (La)TeX in order to obtain corresponding credit, so there is not much context or meaningful content for the article except that I am doing it for a Department of Mathematics at a university.

A properly done Table of Contents is one of the requirements.

Therefore, my question is: in a typical TeX article, what would be the location of the Table of Contents? Would it be after the address but before the introduction?

I don't remember seeing any research articles with a Table of Contents; otherwise, I would try to find one of those and refer to that as an example.

Comment: I have seen articles without Table of contents and another with it (after abstrac)

Comment: What do you mean by "the address"?  And many articles won't have a formal "introduction" section, either.  You're probably in a better position to answer this than we are; you're basically asking us to predict the preferences of your professor.

Comment: By address, I mean the address of the author of the article, which often comes between the abstract and the article body. The article body often starts with an introduction section. All that has been already reviewed and approved, but I was told to add a table of contents.

Comment: If this was one of my professors and the article was not currently in process of grading, I would ask him. But it is one of the department managers, and he gave me a chance to fix the missing table of contents before he gives me a final grade for this.

Comment: The question I have is not what would be preferred by the department manager, but what is standard enough to attract the corresponding points. For example, I am sure that placing the table of contents before the article title would be non-standard enough for me not to get the points for table of contents.

Comment: I don't think that there is a right or wrong answer here. When I add a table of contents to a research article I put it after the abstract.

Comment: You already seem to know an answer that should be good enough to get you points on the exam: If the article has a full titlepage, place the ToC after that page; if there's no separate titlepage, place the ToC *after* any title stuff as well as either before or after the `abstract` (assuming there is one).

Comment: Okay, thanks everyone for the advice. I see that placing the table of contents after the abstract is standard usage, and that's what I will do.